# Decoding jwt token returned by the new google identity api

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-identity

I have created a login button with google identity javascript api https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button#javascript

I have successfully returned a jwt token and decoded it successfully. I have a field in the jwt token called `kid` and the docs say this is its purpose

> the thumbprint for the public key used to verify this token

Will the `kid` field always be the same for the email i logged in with and can it ever change?

I am looking to extract a field from the jwt that will never change so that i can track users who have logged in on web and on android apps.

Comment: probably not im pretty sure the kid is time specific.  Why not test it?  run the login serval times see if it changes.   For tracking uses you should be using the sub claim this is normally the users internal id on the system.

Comment: Yeah its the same but i shall need to at least verify if the token is valid since i can't trust where the token is coming from.

Comment: @DaImTo You are right its time specific. I can verify a token from here https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=<token> So far the "kid": is consistent. How would i obtain the sub claim from google  to identify a user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the id token through [Jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)  The payload data should look something like this.

```
{
  "iss": "accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "1046123799103-q2fg15qscp8apoh8fcf490o3d0bk.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "aud": "1046123799103-q2fg15qscp8apoh8fcf490o3d0bk.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "117200475532672775346",
  "email": "XXXXX@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "at_hash": "LqL3dnsD9w-elE-unya7-g",
  "iat": 1662038461,
  "exp": 1662042061
}
```

In this example the sub is the users internal id on google.

If i run it though the token info endpoint

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=Id_token
```

I get the same sub claim

```
{
  "iss": "accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "1046123799103-q2fg15qscp8apoh8fcf490o3d0bk.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "aud": "1046123799103-q2fg15qscp8apoh8fcf490o3d0bk.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "117200475532672775346",
  "email": "XXXX@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": "true",
  "at_hash": "M_28bzozJTabf3e8Q1yyeQ",
  "iat": "1662045590",
  "exp": "1662049190",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "402f305b70581329ff289b5b3a67283806eca893",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

Sub claim is normally used for account linking between the internal user system of a site and the external third party logins.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing ... almost exactly since i sent the entire jwt token returned from client and got the same info.

Answer (score 1):

you can use base64url_decode function to decode your jwt like that, I had the similar problem that I've solve like that in symfony 5.3:

```
$jwt = $request->request->get('credential');
$match=explode('.',$jwt);

function base64url_decode($base64url)
{
   $base64 = strtr($base64url, '-_', '+/');
   $plainText = base64_decode($base64);
    return ($plainText);
}
  $payload=base64url_decode($match[1]);
  $payloadObject=json_decode($payload);

$verif = $payloadObject->email_verified;
$email = $payloadObject->email;
```

...etc